# Problem with !vtop in windbg for converting a virtual address to a physical one, using the page table address from CR3

Tags: debugging, kernel, x86-64, windbg, page-tables

I study the Windows kernel and windbg ( along the way). And I found the `!vtop` command on msdn - which translates the virtual address of the current context into a physical one. I wanted to enjoy the performance of this team.

My actions:

1. I took the CR3 register as a physical pointer to the PML4 table for the current task - `38f9d002`
2. From the current task, I took a virtual address to translate to physical - `7ff61afa0000`.
3. I enter the command: `!vtop 38f9d002 7ff61afa0000` in WinDbg.
   As a result, I get an error of the following description: `Virtual address 7ff61afa0000 translation fails, error 0xD0000147`.

Full listing from WinDbg:

```
!vtop 38f9d002 7ff61afa0000
Amd64VtoP: Virt 00007ff61afa0000, pagedir 0000000038f9d002
Amd64VtoP: PML4E 0000000038f9d7fa
Amd64VtoP: pagefile PDPE 0:0000000008a00ec0
Amd64VtoP: PML4E not present, 0xD0000147
Virtual address 7ff61afa0000 translation fails, error 0xD0000147.
```

Please tell me where I messed up and what the error code means in general - 0xD0000147, also (if possible) please send a link to the source where I can get acquainted with these codes in detail.

Comment: I don't know WinDBG, but I assuming that virtual address is currently valid, it might not be masking off the process-context-ID bits in the bottom of CR3.  Does it work with `38f9d000` as the PML4 address?  The actual PML4 does have to be 4k-aligned, so the low 12 bits of the physical address will be zero; the low 12 bits of CR3 are special and aren't actually address bits, instead they're flags or other fields.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutly right. The problem turned out to be bit masking. After zeroing out 12 bits, !vtop gave me the correct physical address.
!vtop 49570000 00007FF71A561000
Amd64VtoP: Virt 00007ff71a561000, pagedir 0000000049570000
Amd64VtoP: PML4E 00000000495707f8
Amd64VtoP: PDPE 00000000407fcee0
Amd64VtoP: PDE 000000003467d690
Amd64VtoP: PTE 0000000041e7eb08
Amd64VtoP: Mapped phys 00000000523f6000
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know WinDBG, but assuming that virtual address is currently valid, it probably isn't masking off the process-context-ID bits in the bottom of CR3 for you, so **zero out the low 3 hex digits yourself**.

The OP reports that `38f9d000` does work as the PML4 address.

The actual PML4 has to be 4k-aligned, so the low 12 bits of the physical address will be zero; the low 12 bits of CR3 are special and aren't actually address bits, instead they're flags or other fields.  (Like PCID if that's enabled in another control register.)
https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86-64#CR3 shows the breakdown.